# WordPress slow on MAMP with external DB on local network (2 meters)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp

I am using MAMP on my notebook with WordPress and external database located on my main PC in same local network (via fast WIFI) 1 meter away from notebook.

However WordPress works really slow (5-10 seconds request) if I use this external database connection (MySQL server located at 192.168.1.60:8889).

1. If I use internal database - all is fast.
2. If I use not WordPress, other complex PHP system with same external MySQL server - all works fast as well.
3. If I use external MySQL server in web for WordPress (not in local network), that are thousands kilometers away from me - all is fast too!

Problem only when I use WordPress + MAMP + external MySQL server in MAMP. Anyone know why? I assume issue in some settings in MAMP MySQL or other default configuration..

Comment: Usually you can't access the external database directly even so the  day abase has both Ng to do with mamp so the is nothing to configure. Test a script that checks the runtime of the myql scripts and try to find the bottle neck

Comment: Do you use https:// or http:// ? I am asking because local server might have a certificate problem - and there might be some configuration on your WP site or otherwise MAMP that reuierd a certificate / HTTPS but does have a fallback - and that is what creating the delay ( timeout )